# Is there a tool to add the "override" identifier to existing C++ code

Tags: c++, overriding, c++11

## The task

I am trying to work out how best to add C++0x's [`override`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Explicit_overrides_and_final) identifier to all existing methods that are already overrides in a large body of C++ code, without doing it manually.

(We have many, many hundreds of thousands of lines of code, and doing it manually would be a complete non-starter.)

## Current idea

Our coding standards say that we should add the `virtual` keyword against all implicitly virtual methods in derived classes, even though strictly unnecessary (to aid comprehension).

So if I were to script the addition myself, I'd write a script that read all our headers, found all functions beginning with virtual, and insert `override` before the following semi-colon. Then compile it on a compiler that supports `override`, and fix all the errors in base classes.

But I'd really much rather not use this home-grown way, as:

- it's obviously going to be tedious and error-prone.
- not everyone has remembered, every time, to add the virtual keyword, so this method would miss out some existing overrides

## Is there an existing tool?

So, is there already a tool that parses C++ code, detects existing methods that overrides, and appends `override` to their declarations?

(I am aware of static analysis tools such as [PC-lint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/index.htm) that warn about functions that look like they should be overrides. What I'm after is something that would actually munge our code, so that future errors in overrides will be detected at compiler-time, rather than later on in static analysis)

(In case anyone is tempted to point out that C++03 doesn't support 'override'... In practice, I'd be adding a macro, rather than the actual "override" identifier, to use our code on older compilers that don't support this feature. So after the identifier was added, I'd run a separate script to replace it with whatever macro we're going to use...)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Maybe you can build something based on clang to parse the sources, but I think that it will be an easy task...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a tool under development by the LLVM project called "cpp11-migrate" which currently has the following features:

- convert loops to range-based for loops
- convert null pointer constants (like `NULL` or `0`) to C++11 `nullptr`
- replace the type specifier in variable declarations with the `auto` type specifier
- add the `override` specifier to applicable member functions

This tool is documented [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangTools.html) and should be released as part of  clang 3.3.
However, you can download the source and build it yourself today.

**Edit**

Some more info:

- [Status of the C++11 Migrator](http://blog.llvm.org/2013/04/status-of-c11-migrator.html) - a blog post, dated 2013-04-15
- [cpp11-migrate User’s Manual](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/cpp11-migrate.html)

**Edit 2: 2013-09-07**

"cpp11-migrate" has been renamed to "[clang-modernize](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/ModernizerUsage.html)". For windows users, it is now included in the new [LLVM Snapshot Builds](http://llvm.org/builds/).

**Edit 3: 2020-10-07**

"clang-modernize" has bee renamed to "[Clang-Tidy](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/index.html)".

Comment: Thanks - yes, this works for me. I've been able to build the latest clang and cpp11-migrate from scratch, on Ubuntu, and add override to some sample code. This will be really useful.

Comment: For those people using 64-bit Ubuntu, there is no need in building LLVM stuff by hand. Just install libllvm3.3_3.3-1_amd64.deb and cpp11-migrate-3.3_3.3-1_amd64.deb from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/llvm-toolchain-3.3/ (those packages do not actually require 13.10/Saucy).

Comment: clang-modernize is now [clang-tidy](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/index.html), with certain checks prefaced with "modernize"

Answer (score 7):

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its C++11-capable [C++ Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html) can do this.

DMS is a general purpose program transformation system for arbitrary programming languages; the C++ front end allows it to process C++.  DMS parses, builds ASTs and symbol tables that are accurate (this is hard to do for C++), provides support for querying properties of the AST nodes and trees, allows procedural and source-to-source transformations on the tree.  After all changes are made, the modified tree can be regenerated with comments retained.

Your problem requires that you find derived virtual methods and change them.  A DMS source-to-source transformation rule to do that would look something like:

```
    source domain Cpp.  -- tells DMS the following rules are for C++

    rule insert_virtual_keyword (n:identifier, a: arguments, s: statements):
       method_declaration -> method_declaration " =
       " void \n(\a) { \s } "  ->  " virtual void \n(\a) { \s }"
       if is_implicitly_virtual(n).
```

Such rules match against the syntax trees, so they can't mismatch to a comment, string, or whatever.  The funny quotes are not C++ string quotes; they are meta-quotes to allow the rule language to know that what is inside them has to be treated as target language ("Cpp") syntax. The backslashes are escapes from the target language text, allowing matches to arbitrary structures e.g., \a indicates a need for an "a", which is defined to be the syntactic category "arguments".

You'd need more rules to handle cases where the function returns a non-void result, etc. but you shouldn't need a lot of them.

The fun part is implementing the predicate (returning TRUE or FALSE) controlling application of the transformation: is_implicitly_virtual.  This predicate takes (an abstract syntax tree for) the method name n.
This predicate would consult the full C++ symbol table to determine what n really is.  We already know it is a method from just its syntactic setting, but we want to know in what class context.
The symbol table provides the linkage between the method and class, and the symbol table information for the class tells us what the class inherits from, and for those classes, which methods they contain and how they are declared, eventually leading to the discovery (or not) that the parent class method is virtual.   The code to do this has to be implemented as procedural code going against the C++ symbol table API.  However, all the hard work is done; the symbol table is correct and contains references to all the other data needed.  (If you don't have this information, you can't possibly decide algorithmically, and any code changes will likely be erroneous).

DMS has been used to carry out massive changes on C++ code in the past using program transformations.(Check the Papers page at the web site for C++ rearchitecting topics).

(I'm not a C++ expert, merely the DMS architect, so if I have minor detail wrong, please forgive.)

Comment: Thanks very much. I was actually after adding `override`, not `virtual`. But I hadn't heard at the tool, so I will have a look at it.

Comment: It took me a while to find the 'Papers' page, so here's the URL: http://www.semdesigns.com/Company/Publications/

Comment: How well does the tool preserve formatting?  For instance, in our code base functions with excessively long parameter lists **usually** have the parameters placed on separate lines.  What's tricky is that there are no hard rules, just human intuition (make it readable).  I would hate to have to tool munge the entire declaration when it could be a one word addition.

Comment: @deft_code: The tool can run with pretty-printed output, e.g., an enforced style independent of what was read (that style can be altered); but in general, everybody hates a style they didn't define. It can also be run in "fidelity mode", which preserves the layout as much as practical (it tries to preserve the column numbers of the tokens). Where the code has changed, it obviously can't do that, and it can't guess at intended style. So it falls back on its prettyprinting rules there. You didn't ask about other formatting issues (radix of numbers, etc.) but we get that right.

Comment: Although I haven't yet been able to try out DMS, I've read a lot about it, and it sounds very promising. So I am accepting this as the right answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Ira Could you provide a download link to DMS, i really can't see through the website.

Comment: @RedX: We don't offer a DMS "try it for a day" download because it isn't practical to try it in a day.   Most would-be users go through a series of confidence building exercises to both build up their understanding of what they need to do to use it effectively, and whether the problem they have will benefit from applying it.  (The above Q&A is a first step for OP).  Often this involves a phone conversation for a high-bandwidth exchange.  I suggest you contact the company (see my bio), and start that conversation.

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this a few months ago with about 3 MB worth of code and while you say that "doing it manually would be a complete non-starter," I think it is the only way.  The reason is that you should be applying the override keyword to the prototypes that are **intended** to override base class methods.  Any tool that adds it will put it on the prototypes that **actually** override base class methods.  The compiler already knows which methods those are so adding the keyword doesn't change anything.  (Please note that I am not terribly familiar with the new standard and I am assuming the override keyword is optional.  Visual Studio has supported override since at least VS2005.)

I used a search for "virtual" in the header files to find most of them and I still occasionally find another prototype that is missing the override keyword.

I found two bugs by going through that.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I take your point about intended versus actual. I feel there would still be value in getting the majoriity of override identifiers adding automatically, and then reviewing the headers for what remains. (And actually we do have PC-Lint to review for likely errors, too)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse CDT has a working C++ parser and semantic utilities. The latest version IIRC also has markers for overriding methods.

It wouldn't require much code to write a plug-in which would base on that and rewrite the code to contain the `override` tags where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

one option is to

Enable suggest-override compiler warning  And then write a script
    which can insert override keyword to location pointed by the emitted warnings

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion - the question is around finding an existing tool though, not writing a script to do it...