# How can I add the override keyword to a large C++ codebase?

Tags: c++, overriding

I have a large C++ codebase with thousands of source files. I want to add the `override` keyword wherever it's appropriate. Some of my apparently-overridden functions do not actually override any function from the base class, and I'd like to catch these or at least make them stand out.

I tried doing it manually, but the codebase is too large. I tried using clang-modernize, but it doesn't come with useful instructions. I'm also concerned that it won't be able to comprehend the codebase written for Visual Studio.

How can I add the override keyword to my codebase without spending man-weeks or more on the task?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding. What exactly is your current situation, and why do you need to change it?

Comment: @RedRoboHood: I'd interpret it as a desire to migrate already-working code to modern best-practice (to help prevent errors going forward).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes, I understand that; I was asking for more details about his specific problem. I think I get it now, though (I was mixing up `override` with `operator` for a minute).

Comment: @RedRoboHood I've found several instances where function signatures don't match between base class virtual declaration and the eventual derived class. I'm sure there are more instances and I'd like to tackle this class of problem in my codebase. The override keyword would mostly solve my problem, if I can find an affordable way to add the keyword. Does that make sense?

Comment: Use [Clang-MR](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub41342.html)? (Though I think the authors would disagree about the meaning of the word 'large'.)

Comment: @Sophit You should roll that clarification into your question.  It may be that there are other solutions to your actual problem that you haven't considered (Me saying that without a solid grasp of your issues)

Comment: @KerrekSB do you have a link to binaries and instructions?

Comment: @Sophit: No, I think you need to develop that yourself. It's just a resarch idea.

Comment: As far as I know, I do not think there is any easy or quick way to do this other then going into each header file and changing each class's declarations directly. It is tedious, long and boring! I would try starting out with all classes that are at the lowest priority of being a base class and work up the hierarchy one level at a time.

Comment: You could automate this in VS using the EnvDTE API to traverse your codebase and insert the keyword where appropriate.

Comment: See also multiple useful answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293715/is-there-a-tool-to-add-the-override-identifier-to-existing-c-code

Answer (score 2):

It seems that clang-modernize has moved into [clang-tidy](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/index.html) which supports this.

Example code (test.cpp):

```
struct Base {
    virtual void reimplementMe(int a) {}
};
struct Derived : public Base  {
    virtual void reimplementMe(int a) {}
};
```

clang-tidy invocation (dry run):

```
clang-tidy-6.0 -checks='modernize-use-override' test.cpp -- -std=c++11
```

To actually fix your code (be sure to have a working backup):

```
clang-tidy-6.0 -checks='modernize-use-override' -fix test.cpp -- -std=c++11
```

Giving:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void reimplementMe(int a) {}
};
struct Derived : public Base  {
    void reimplementMe(int a) override {}
};
```

---

Note: Example from [this great article](https://www.kdab.com/clang-tidy-part-1-modernize-source-code-using-c11c14/) was used -- have a look for a detailed explanation and check it's [next part](https://www.kdab.com/clang-tidy-part-2-integrate-qmake-and-other-build-systems-using-bear/) which describes how to convert a larger project.

Good luck!